# Blob doesn't exist on type 'Object' error - Downloading excel file from post call using Angular 4

Tags: angular, http-post, blob, angular2-observables, angular4-httpclient

Front End: Angular 4
Back End: Java(RestFul Web Service)

My rest call returns a excel as response. I have written the code to return that same file to the user.

My Controller:

```
exportExcelXSL() {
    var excelData;
    console.log("Excel");
    console.log(this.workRequestSearchBasicReq);
    this.workRequestSearchBasicReq.OrdersPerPage = undefined;
    let request = Utility.removeUndefinedNullFields(this.workRequestSearchBasicReq);
    console.log(request);
    var data = {};
    data["ICWRQry"] = Utility.removeUndefinedNullFields(request);

    this.workRequest.workRequestReport(data).subscribe(data => {
        var mediaType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
        let blob: Blob = data.blob();
          window['saveAs'](blob, 'sample.xls');
      });
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

My Service:

```
workRequestReport(searchOrderReq: any): Observable<Blob> {
let workRequestSearchBeanShellUrl = "http://localhost:7001/uuigui/uui/eapp/iVAPP/WorkRequestSearchReport";
return this.httpClient.post(workRequestSearchBeanShellUrl, searchOrderReq,  {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'responseType': 'ResponseContentType.Blob '})
 }).map(data => data.blob());
}
```

But in console, I am getting error as *"property 'blob' does not exist on type 'Object'"* error in both `Service(Line:map(data => data.blob());)` & `Controller(Line:let blob: Blob = data.blob();)`

Can somebody help me to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can update `workRequestReport` method to the following

```
workRequestReport(searchOrderReq: any): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
let workRequestSearchBeanShellUrl = "http://localhost:7001/uuigui/uui/eapp/iVAPP/WorkRequestSearchReport";
return this.httpClient.post(workRequestSearchBeanShellUrl, searchOrderReq, {
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'blob' 
    });
}
```

Comment: I can only comment about the service call, and that would be fine with the modified service method. If you want  this.cd.detectChanges() to be called after the saveAs block, then move it inside the subscribe block.